# python: numpy reshaping an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am creating a numpy array using the following:

```
X = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=500)
```

This generates points evenly sampled 500 points between -5 and 5. The shape of the resulting array is: `(500,)`. Now, I need to pass it to a function that expects a 2-D array. So, I can reshape it as:

```
X = X.reshape((500, 1))
```

However, I noticed that `X = X[:, None]` has the same effect. For the life of me though, I cannot understand what this syntax is doing. Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: `None` is `np.newaxis` - [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on advanced indexing explains its use in a bit of detail and might be a useful reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `X[: ,None]` is actually the same as:

```
X[:, np.newaxis]
```

which is adding a new dimension to your original array.

Answer (score 3):

The Python interpreter translates

```
 x[:,None]
```

to

```
 x.__getitem__((slice(None,None,None), None))
```

and the `ndarray` implementation of `__getitem__` acts in much the same way as `x.reshape(500,1)`.  Implementation details will differ, but the effect is the same.  `

So at a syntax level, it's just normal Python.  But the `numpy` semantics give it a distinctive meaning.

```
 x[:, np.newaxis]
```

may be clearer, but `np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None`:

```
In [48]: np.newaxis is None
Out[48]: True
```